# Replace low res video with High res HD video

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm creating a site with full browser video (see http://bitstream.ca/).
For an optimum experience I'd like to use a low quality video file first and download a high res video in the background. When the high res has fully downloaded I want to swap out the low res. Pretty sure this is possible using javascript along with some listeners of the video object, but am unsure how to proceed.
Can anyone help?

Comment: To me this doesn't sound like an optimal experience. For people on a slow connection downloading two videos at the same time is going to be a waste of bandwidth and perhaps the hi-res version wont load in time. For people on a fast connection it is going to be a waste since a lo-res version is being downloaded for no reason.

Comment: Not to mention, use a ton more bandwidth on your server. Why not put effort into ensuring that you have the bandwidth to deliver video faster than real-time (eg, so it takes less time to stream than to play it back)? This would entail having a solid hosting environment (and/or using a CDN) and using a high-compression codec

Comment: From a user experience point of view, this may also be less than desirable. Do you expect users to sit through a low quality version for a few minutes while they wait for the high quality to stream, and then suddenly switch them up? Many people won't want to see the low quality version at all, and will find this behaviour irritating. Depending on the nature of your site, you may lose visitors: they click to watch a purportedly "high-quality" video, get a crappy quality one instead, and then leave after 5 seconds.

Comment: I'm talking about a 5to 10 second looping background video so I respectfully disagree with the above, though appreciate the feedback. What I'm trying to do is minimize any delay before the video appears and begins to play

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using JavaScript to detect the users bandwidth and then with the result decide if the hi-res or low-res version should be downloaded.

This [post](http://blog.weareon.net/bandwidth-detection-with-javascript/) should provide a good starting point.

Comment: Link is dead. Archived version [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20130622001045/http://blog.weareon.net/bandwidth-detection-with-javascript).

Answer (score -1):

If your viewer support switching, then you can calculate the time when the download finish and launch the high res in the background. Give it a second before switching it to the fore ground.