# Auto select appropriate video quality depending upon network bandwidth?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, html, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 types of video:

- 720x720,
- 480x480 and
- 320x320.

How to select automatically quality of video depending on network throughput of the user?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8221509/218196

Comment: @FelixKling 404 (Page Not Found) Error

Comment: Yeah well, that's the problem with links... :-/

Comment: the site at all doesn't work. =((

Comment: @user3311412 Archived version [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20130622001045/http://blog.weareon.net/bandwidth-detection-with-javascript).

Answer (score 7):

**Step 1**

Upload an image around size of 1Mb somewhere on your server. You must know exact size of image in bytes and image's URL.

**Step 2**

```
var imageAddr = "IMAGE_URL_HERE";
imageAddr += "?n="+Math.random();
var startTime, endTime;
var downloadSize = SIZE_OF_IMAGE_IN_BYTES;
var download = new Image();
download.onload = function () {
    endTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    showResults();
}
startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
download.src = imageAddr;

function showResults() {
    var duration = (endTime - startTime) / 1000; //Math.round()
    var bitsLoaded = downloadSize * 8;
    var speedBps = (bitsLoaded / duration).toFixed(2);
    var speedKbps = (speedBps / 1024).toFixed(2);
    var speedMbps = (speedKbps / 1024).toFixed(2);

    if(speedMbps<1){
    //LOAD_SMALL_VIDEO
    }

    else if(speedMbps<2){
    //LOAD_MEDIUM_VIDEO
    }

    else {
    //LOAD_LARGE_VIDEO
    }

}
```